# Need help regarding parallelization for 300 websocket connections in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a trading bot in python for Binance platform. I have selected 300 cryptos. Binance has a websocket API for each  pair. I am able to fetch price data for one pair. I need to parallely fetch prices for 300 cryptos and do some calculations. The data is pushed every 100ms. Each pair has a different url. So I guess I need to open 300 websocket connections in parallel.

All of this should be done under 100 ms and store the data in a single list. I haven't used multiprocessing, multithreading, asyncio etc so I have no I idea how to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

1. Use a *.yaml with all urls as config file
2. Have an empty and global list in the main thread where you will store the newest value (list) or more (dict) sent by each socket url
3. Open 1 socket per url in an own Thread with threading.thread.
4. Check if you have to ping from time to time so your client isnt disconnected.